# Simplest way to run a for loop in parallel in python

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

How can I parallelize this?

```
 for j, paths in enumerate(shortest_paths):
     if len(paths) > 1:
        for i in range(len(paths) - 1):
           some_dict[(paths[i], paths[i + 1])] += demand[j]
```

I have a million shortest paths.

The above code is inside a function inside a class definition. So I want to run it as parallel inside the function itself. Multiprocessing.pool requires me to write a function for this and then call multiprocessing in `__main__` which is not possible. Can you suggest me the simplest and cleanest way to dp this?

Comment: no, multi-processing doesn't require you to run main, it requires you to write a worker function that can be run in a different process. Even if it was in main, why would that be impossible? ProcessingPoolExecutor and ThreadPoolExecutor are your "cleanest" ways of doing this, but with threads you need to worry about GIL for the time being (although PEP 703 is trying to change that https://peps.python.org/pep-0703/)

Comment: Why do you want to parallelize that? Doesn't look like that would be faster. But you could make it faster with better code than that.

Comment: @KellyBundy Why not? I can say look into 1/8th of the shortest path list in each thread and get the link demands and then sum the 8 link demands. Wont that cut run times by 1/8th?

Comment: @EpicCoder I see, still isnt there something simpler which can parallelise a for loop. Something like a decorator?

Comment: CPython multithreading cannot help to speed up such a code because of the *GIL*. With multiprocessing, each *process* each have its own memory. Thus you need to distribute the input so each process operate on different parts efficiently. Numpy arrays can be shared between processes (thanks to *shared memory* mapping) but then you will likely need locks, especially since you write into an array (and locks are slow because of a more serialized execution and additional overheads). The operation will certainly *not* scale well due to the way CPUs works (cache lines and DRAM).

Comment: Anyway, the current code is completely **bound by Numpy overheads**. It would be a huge disaster to use more resources (i.e. core) to make it faster. It will just *waste* more resources. The first thing to do is to execute native code using Numba or Cython or any native language (e.g. C). I expect the code to be 10x to 100x times faster just with that.

Comment: @new_here Because it looks like the work each process would do is proportional to its data size, and faster than the data transfer. There are soon many questions here where people did that and asked why multiprocessing made their program much *slower*.

Comment: @JérômeRichard *"the current code is completely bound by Numpy overhead"* - Is there any NumPy here? I don't see it.

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh, right! I used to read too many Numpy post but this one is not tagged with numpy ^^" . To be more correct, it will be bound by the *CPython interpreter overheads* (since the OP likely uses CPython) or the overhead of the data structure (which is likely a map making random-like memory accesses). So still overheads, but not particularly Numpy ones indeed.

Comment: @KellyBundy Using arrays should help by the way if this is not the case. It would make memory accesses more predictable and certainly more contiguous too. Hard to tell precisely without types and actually a complete code...